# How to check if there is some value inside array of objects (which is also an object) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this object in js:

```
var list = {
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "start_date": "2019-01-14",
    "end_date": "2019-01-14",
    "text": "some text one",
    "assistent": "12"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "start_date": "2021-12-01",
    "end_date": "2021-12-01",
    "text": "another text",
    "assistent": "15"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": "3",
    "start_date": "2021-12-02",
    "end_date": "2021-12-02",
    "text": "one more text",
    "assistent": "2"
  } 
}
```

I want to check, if there is an "assistent"=2 inside this array of objects, and, if yes, get a "text" parameter for this assistent (it have to be "one more text"). What i have tried:

```
var foundtext = list.find(x => x.assistent === '2').text;
console.log(foundtext);
```

(will show that .find is not a function)
Also:

```
var foundtext = list.find(x => x.assistent == '2')['text'];
console.log(foundtext);
```

(will show the same error)

Also tried this:

```
for (var i=1; i <= list.length; i++) {
console.log(list[i]);
//and than perform the search inside list[i];
}
```

and this :

```
list.forEach(value => {
  console.log(value);
//and than perform the search inside value;
})
```

So what is the right approach to perform this kind of check?

Comment: `list` is not an array `[]` so `find` and `forEach` will not be defined methods you can call. Try using an array instead?

Comment: You have done very good attempts. Please know that the variable `list` is an Object. We are able to iterate over an object using `for ... of` loop - or by using `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, `Object.entries()`. In your case, you may want to try `Object.values(list).filter(x => x.assistent === '2')[0].text` - to get the desired `text`.

Comment: Thank you guys, Object.values() is what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```js
const text = Object.values(list).find(entry => entry.assistent === "2")?.text
```

EDIT

For the additional question in the comments below.

```js
const texts = Object.values(list)
                    .filter(entry => entry.assistent === "2")
                    .map(entry => entry.text)
```

Comment: that's it, man!

Comment: what i can add to find all "text" values for a case, when we have assistent="2" several times in object?

Comment: @AntonySlahin I've added a response for your follow up question.

Comment: Yes, so i will get an array of found texts, and than i can work with this array, for example, with forEach. Good news for me, many thanks